# How to build custom drag&drop email modules

Tags: email-template, email-studio

my client would like to have custom modules in SFMC.
I would like to know how to build a boilerplate with header and footer; and how to build draggable modules.

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Dario

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site tends to work best when you have a very specific problem, and can show us what you've tried so far. If you're new to Salesforce, or just new to a feature therein, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is a better resource to get a handle on the basics.

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you very much for sending me this. I did search in trailhead.salesforce.com but nothing i wanted. I have HTML email developer questions about how to build drag-and-drop custom modules in a reusable template with header and footer. Thank you again